# Нужен ли gunicorn для web-socket-сервера?

Tags: python-3.5, gunicorn, systemd

Настроил связку nginx + gunicorn + мое web-socket-приложение по [этой](https://quantrum.me/599-zapusk-aiohttp-s-pomoshhyu-gunicorn-i-nginx/) статье. Только gunicorn у меня управляется не супервизором, а systemctl, запускается на старте системы как демон вместе с моим app. Приложение асинхронное, использует asyncio и aiohttp. Но, пока не могу понять, нужен ли gunicorn? Что он дает, можно ли без него? И еще такой вопрос: если запускать app без gunicorn, непосредственно под systemctl(systemd, не знаю как правильней), то при systemctl stop MyApp как и какой сигнал мне ловить в приложении?

Comment: что вы хотите в ответе увидеть: "нет не нужен: возможно запустить приложение и без gunicorn" или "да, нужен:  gunicorn позволяет избежать в ручную запускать процессы". Посмотрите на [server deployment](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/deployment.html) в документации: перечислены несколько опций и их основные достоинства/недостатки.

Comment: Я смотрел эти доки, но отношусь к ним как к доведенной до предела сжатой информации. Хотел бы услышать что-то вроде "гуникорн скорее полезен в данной связке, по причинам таким-то", или наоборот. Подозреваю, что реальность намного сложнее и обширнее, чем то, что описано в доках.